# NoSuchElementException: No Line Found with hasNextLine

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I have included a hasNextLine exception, but I am still receiving the NoSuchElementException error

I am creating a palindrome program that scans from a file. I can get it to scan from the file, but it only returns the non-palindrome words, and returns an err of NoSuchElementException: No Line Found, even though I have included a hasNextLine.

```
case 3:
            System.out.println("Palindrome problem.");

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {          
        String text, reverse = input.nextLine();            
        text = input.nextLine();             
        int length = text.length();   
        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )  
        reverse = reverse + text.charAt(i);  
            if (text.equals(reverse))  
            System.out.println(text + "is a palindrome.");  
                else  
                System.out.println(text + "isn't a palindrome.");    
    }
            break;
```

I would like the code to read the entire file and return both palindromes and non-palindrome words

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling the `input.nextLine()` twice here:

```
String text, reverse = input.nextLine();            
text = input.nextLine();
```

When `text = input.nextLine();` is executed the line is already consumed.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a play with deleting that line.

Comment: If I delete this line, how do I declare "text" then?

Comment: @Strato `String reverse = input.nextLine();` `String text =  reverse;`